# Parallel makefile requires dependency ordering

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following piece of makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x -Wall
SRCS     = test1.cpp test2.cpp
OBJDIR   = object
OBJS     = $(SRCS:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

all: test1 
release: clean test1

test1: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MD -c -o $@ $<

-include $(SRCS:.cpp=.d)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*

.PHONY: all clean release
```

Now if I try to invoke "make -j4 release" the clean target often gets execute in the middle of building files which causes compilation to fail. My question is how to ensure that the clean target has completed before starting the release build.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

My preference is for

```
release:
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) test1
```

This forces the two targets to be made consecutively without disturbing their inner parallelism (if any).

Comment: This works, hovever, the parameter passed in (-j4) is ommited for the make calls. So `make release` and `make -j4 release` take exactly the same amount of time and the problem of OP is not solved i think.

Comment: @jrast I'm not sure what you're trying to say there, but if `make clean` or `make test1` would be faster with `-j4`, then `make -j4 release` will take advantage of that, but without starting `make test1` before `make clean` has finished.

Comment: Is the `-j4` parameter passed to the subsequent `make` calls? Yesterday it did not look like that (based on the time it took to compile), but now I rececked at indeed, the timing of `make clean && make all` is about the same as `make release`.

Comment: @jrast `-j<n>` is a special case, but in general make flags are automatically passed down to submakes via the `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable.

Answer (score 13):

You may split the execution into non-parallel (for `release`) and parallel (for the rest targets) phases.

```
ifneq ($(filter release,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
.NOTPARALLEL:
endif

release: clean
    $(MAKE) test1
```

[`.NOTPARALLEL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_002eNOTPARALLEL-238) target will suppress parallel execution if `release` target is mentioned in the command line. The `release` target itself will rerun Make after cleaning and build `test1` in parallel.

### UPD.

More clever solution would also reinvoke Make for each single target in case if there are more than one targets given on the command-line, so that a presence of `release` target would not force the rest to execute non-parallel too.

```
ifneq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1)
.NOTPARALLEL:
$(sort all $(MAKECMDGOALS)):
    @$(MAKE) -f $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $@
else
# ...
endif
```

### Update by [James Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562766/james-johnston)

The clever solution above doesn't work on versions of GNU make that don't support job servers.  For example, released MinGW/native builds of GNU make prior to version 4.0 do not support job servers.  (Cygwin/MSYS builds of GNU make do.)  The code below uses the [`.FEATURES` variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eFEATURES-_0028list-of-supported-features_0029) introduced in make 3.81 to detect if job servers are supported.  The symptom of not using this workaround when it's needed is that your "parallel" build will be serialized.

```
# Check if job server supported:
ifeq ($(filter jobserver, $(.FEATURES)),)
# Job server not supported: sub-makes will only start one job unless
# you specify a higher number here.  Here we use a MS Windows environment
# variable specifying number of processors.
JOBSARG := -j $(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)
else
# Job server is supported; let GNU Make work as normal.
JOBSARG :=
endif

# .FEATURES only works in GNU Make 3.81+.
# If GNU make is older, assume job server support.
ifneq ($(firstword $(sort 3.81 $(MAKE_VERSION))),3.81)
# If you are using GNU Make < 3.81 that does not support job servers, you
# might want to specify -jN parameter here instead.
JOBSARG :=
endif

ifneq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1)
.NOTPARALLEL:
# The "all" target is required in the list,
# in case user invokes make with no targets.
$(sort all $(MAKECMDGOALS)):
    @$(MAKE) $(JOBSARG) -f $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $@
else

# Put remainder of your makefile here.

endif
```

Comment: That's a big hit in performance. You delete all the files, and then rebuild with once CPU???

Comment: @bobbogo No. The actual rebuilding is performed by a sub-make, which executes its commands in parallel. The only point where `.NOTPARALLEL` takes an effect is `release` target of the **top-level** make invocation. Did you ever read the answer before downvoting?

Comment: Ah, I see. `.NOTPARALLEL` does not not affect recursive calls to make. Fiendish!

Comment: If `make` was run with several targets, the `.NOTPARALLEL` will affect all of the targets given to the top-level `make`, will it not?

Comment: @Kevin, yes, it will. However, one could reinvoke `make` for each target, please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the release case, you need to ensure that `clean` completes before *any* compiling. Thus you (just) add it as a dependency to the compile rule (and not to the phony target). Several ways of doing this, like target-specific variables, or:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(if $(filter release,${MAKECMDGOALS}),clean)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what versions this feature is supported in, but you can use the `order-only` feature:

```
my_target: dep1 dep2 | must_run_1st must_run_2nd
```

All dependencies left of the `|` character are processed as normal. Dependencies to the right of `|` are run 'order-only'

This feature is described at:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html

In your case, the following rules definition would suffice:

```
release: | clean test1
test1: | clean
```

Comment: Sadly, this feature doesn't actually help. The actual ordering of several order-only prerequisites in a single list has no meaningful effect - they'll still run simultaneously if you use parallel `make`. This is because "order-only" is a misnomer - all an order-only prerequisite does is avoid triggering a rebuild of the target if the prerequisite is newer, and it's only really suitable for ensuring a destination directory exists (as the example in the GNU `make` docs indicates!)

Comment: "Order-only" isn't a misnomer: it means exactly what it says; these prerequisites are considered only in terms of ensuring that they are built before the target, and not considered when determining whether the target is out of date.  They are useful in any situation where you want to be sure that one target is built before another but not force the second to be rebuilt whenever the first is updated.

Answer (score -1):

For a solution without a recursive invocation of make, you could try this.

```
ifneq ($(filter release,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
test1: clean
endif
```

Comment: @kyku: Too bad, although I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @eriktous: That's because the prerequisites of test1 don't also depend on "clean."  Basically, you are needing to have clean be a prerequisite for every single rule.  So, make is still free to do "clean", "hello.o", and "secondFile.o" in parallel (assuming the .o files are prereqs of test1) - you only forbade it from running "clean" in parallel with "test1."