# makefile parallel clean+compile issue

Tags: makefile

I have a simple makefile with 3 build rules:

1. clean (that cleans the .o)
2. debug (compiles my code with debgging stuff)
3. release (compiles my code with optimization stuff)

sometimes I want to switch between debug mode and release so I would issue this

```
make clean debug -j8
```

or

```
make clean release -j8
```

that has a drawback because while it's doing the clean stuff, the -j8 allows make to *jump* some command since the .o are still there Then those .o are removed by the clean rule and the compiler complains because it can't find those .o

I could do something like

```
make clean; make debug -j8
```

but since I use an odd makefile in another dir, the command becomes

```
make -C ../src -f nMakefile clean ; make -C ../src -f nMakefile -j8 release
```

that is more annoying. I was wondering if there was an **hiddedn-guru-mode-rule** that allows me to do it in one line

Hope it's clear enough...

Comment: Creating two new targets would solve it. I mean clean_release and clean_debug. Also you should not need to clean when switching if you direct objects to different sub-directories depending on release/debug. I think having different subdirs is the way you should go.

Comment: do you mean adding
    clean_release: clean release

Comment: I was wondering if "order-only prerequisites" (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) could be used to solve this, but haven't managed to get it working so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated above, the normal practice is to have different sub directories for the object files. As you are running in parallel I would think you need to enforce serial execution so that clean is completed before release. One way of doing it could be:

```
clean_release: clean
    +@$(MAKE) -s --no-print-directory release
```

or if you prefer

```
clean_release:
    +@$(MAKE) -s --no-print-directory clean && $(MAKE) -s --no-print-directory release
```

Comment: Simple, but this doesn't work if you need to specify "clean" along with several other targets manually specified on the command line - like how the author specified.  E.g. what if he wants to `make clean debug release -j8` ?  (Atmel Studio is an example of an IDE that forces you to do it this way, BTW...)  I think the answer from Eldar at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496135/parallel-makefile-require-depency-ordering is a good way to do it...  it just serializes all targets passed on command line - doesn't care about the names or how many.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to solve this very same problem, and the solution I came up was to parse the `MAKECMDGOALS` for `clean`, and dispatch a shell command to do the actual cleaning work; RATHER than clean the build as a target. This way, any `MAKECMDGOALS` that include "clean" will clean the build as part of that build, first, sequentially, rather than `clean` running asynchronously as its own target.

```
-include $(deps)
bin/%.o : %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $@D
    g++ $(flags) $(includes) -MMD -c $< -o $@

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    @echo rm -rf bin/

ifneq ($(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
    $(shell rm -rf bin/)
endif
```