# The `re` recipe doesn't always recompile the library if --jobs is greater than 1

Tags: c, makefile

## My problem with `re`

I have a problem with the `re` recipe in my `Makefile` when I have `--jobs` greater than 1.

When I run `make re --jobs=N` it successfully **deletes** the object files and the archive via `fclean`. It then sucessfully **recompiles** the library via `all` if `N=1`:

```bash
$ make re --jobs=1

rm -rf obj/
rm -f library.a
mkdir -p obj/
cc -c -Wall -Werror -Wextra func01.c -o obj/func01.o
...
cc -c -Wall -Werror -Wextra func37.c -o obj/func37.o
ar -crs library.a obj/func01.o ... obj/func37.o
```

However, if `N>1`, it always makes `fclean` but only makes `all` every 2nd in 2 consecutive runs:

```bash
$ make re --jobs=2

rm -rf obj/
rm -f libft.a

$ make re --jobs=2

rm -rf obj/
rm -f library.a
mkdir -p obj/
cc -c -Wall -Werror -Wextra func01.c -o obj/func01.o
...
cc -c -Wall -Werror -Wextra func37.c -o obj/func37.o
ar -crs library.a obj/func01.o ... obj/func37.o
```

I think it tries to make `fclean` and `all` simultaneously and doesn't finish the recipe correctly every 1st in 2 runs. Is this even possible? Do I forget it and just use `--jobs=1` or do I fix it and make it work for any number of `--jobs`? How?

## My `Makefile`

It's a `Makefile` that compiles a *certain* library archive (`library.a`) for a *certain* school project. I have 1 **C header** file (`library.h`) and 37 explicitly listed **C source** files (`func01.c ... func37.c`). The compiled **object** files have a dedicated `obj/` directory. The `Makefile` does **not relink** and looks like this:

```makefile
NAME    :=  library.a
CFLAGS  :=  -Wall -Werror -Wextra

H_FILES :=  library.h
C_FILES :=  func01.c ... func37.c

O_DIR   :=  obj/
O_FILES :=  $(C_FILES:%.c=$(O_DIR)%.o)

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(O_FILES)
    ar -crs $@ $^

$(O_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(O_FILES): $(O_DIR)%.o: %.c $(H_FILES) | $(O_DIR)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(O_DIR)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all
```

## My environment

I use **GNU Make 4.1** built for *x86_64-pc-linux-gnu* on **Debian GNU/Linux** under **WSL** (*Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux*).

Comment: The first answer on that question shows how create a rebuild target which does clean in parallel, then does the build in parallel, with the clean finishing before the build is started.

Comment: Thank you! This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496739/7212563 I did rely on the order of prerequisites, but now I explicitly specified a sequence of two submakes: first for `fclean`, then for `all`.